# Quick question on centralising image - Beginner here

Tags: html

a beginner in HTML here.

I have a quick question on aligning an image to be centralised - the Hover over shadow shows that my image is just few pixels off to the right:
[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4jqF.jpg)

[Another Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6Wbh.jpg)

My HTML code is as follows. Thanks in advance!!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

div.gallery:hover {
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease-in-out;  
}

div.gallery img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

div.desc {
  font-family: 'Open Sans'
  padding: 0px;
padding-top: 10px;
font-size: 18px;
  color: #03308D;
  text-align: center;
}

div.desc2 {
  font-family: 'Open Sans'
  padding: 20px;
padding-top: 5px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
font-size: 14px;
  color: #03308D;
  text-align: center;
}


.responsive {
  padding: 20px;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .responsive {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 6px 0;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .responsive {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="responsive">
  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="www.google.com">
      <img src="https://rmkcdn.successfactors.com/a6c5af8d/019942b5-bb07-49d5-ad5b-4.jpg" alt="Forest" width="600" height="400">
    </a>
    <div class="desc"> <b> Graduate Associates </b> <br/></div>
<div class="desc2">Description<br/> </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Also advise if there's any redundant HTML codes in the above snippet, thank you in advance!

Comment: The Image does look centered in this snippet, but in where I'm using this, the image is just few pixels to the right

Answer (score 0):

It is centered in your code can see using background color.
If not centered where are you using this then either use :

> Resize image according to need here used small only to demonstrate , change   `div.gallery img {width: 50%;}` for that

```
.gallery a{
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}
```

**Like in below snippet (used color to deppicts the area covered by element and to show whether centered or not)**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

div.gallery a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-flow: column;
  background-color: blue;
}

div.gallery:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

div.gallery img {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
}

div.desc {
  font-family: 'Open Sans' padding: 0px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #03308D;
  text-align: center;
}

div.desc2 {
  font-family: 'Open Sans' padding: 20px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #03308D;
  text-align: center;
}

.responsive {
  padding: 20px;
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .responsive {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 6px 0;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .responsive {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="responsive">
  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="www.google.com">
      <img src="https://rmkcdn.successfactors.com/a6c5af8d/019942b5-bb07-49d5-ad5b-4.jpg" alt="Forest" width="600" height="400">
    </a>
    <div class="desc"> <b> Graduate Associates </b> <br/></div>
    <div class="desc2">Description<br/> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**or**

```
.gallery img{
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto
}
```

**like in below snippet**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

div.gallery:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

div.gallery img {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

div.desc {
  font-family: 'Open Sans' padding: 0px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #03308D;
  text-align: center;
}

div.desc2 {
  font-family: 'Open Sans' padding: 20px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #03308D;
  text-align: center;
}

.responsive {
  padding: 20px;
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .responsive {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 6px 0;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .responsive {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="responsive">
  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="www.google.com">
      <img src="https://rmkcdn.successfactors.com/a6c5af8d/019942b5-bb07-49d5-ad5b-4.jpg" alt="Forest" width="600" height="400">
    </a>
    <div class="desc"> <b> Graduate Associates </b> <br/></div>
    <div class="desc2">Description<br/> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Some extra `margin/padding` may be added to some side which create some pixel difference

Comment: Thanks Rana!
The first code changes the image dimensions completely, while the 2nd code doesn't have any effect

Comment: You have to add `flex-flow: column` in first way

Comment: Shown the image is centered using `flex` in above answer . Used a some extra lines of code

Comment: Also make a habit of using `*{box-sizing: border-box}` to remove major problems of overflowing of content out of its container